# Modx Revolution - How to Call a Resource Document

Tags: resources, document, modx

With ModX Revolution, I'm able to setup a set of TVs to create an Editable slideshow and assign the TV to whatever template resource I want. (checked)

The problem is that if I want to run the Slideshow on different documents, the values for the slideshow have to be set on EACH document that the TVs are assigned to and this is a hassle because my goal is to create a set of TVs and once the values are set, this values (images, text, w/e) should appear on every document (template, page, etc) but instead, I have to input the same repeated data on each one of them.

Then I thought of this. What if I could create a resource document for the slideshow only and then call this document to w/e page I want? The idea sounds good to me as it would allow me to edit the TV values on a single document and display it anywhere I want to but the thing is that I don't know how to call a Resource Document at all.

It goes like this.

- Create a Chunk [[$slider]] which contains the slider template.
- Create a set of TVs. (one of each image) [[*slider1]], [[*slider2]], etc.
- Place the TVs inside the slider chunk and replace the image links with the TVs. This allows for the images to be easily changed by simply uploading an image to an album and calling the image within the TV.
- Place the [[$slider]] chunk inside the template I want it to appear and then call that template document inside another document.

I hope this is clear enough of an explanation.

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried BannerY extra -  http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/BannerY ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I hadn't consider that but after looking at the link you provided, it will still keep me around the same loop. Since I'm customizing the template to be easily managed and the images changed by a simple "image" TVs set, using this would make it more complex for the people that will be handling the website.

Comment: I have already created a slider with it's template and properties and the images is the only thing I need called but I want them to be called by simply uplading them thru a TV. I have it fully working but the problem is that I have to upload the image on each page that has the slideshow included and that's what I'm trying to avoid. I want to create a single "Document" that will have the slider template and the TVs assigned and I want to call that "Document" on every page that needs the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Install [MIGX](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/MIGX) via Package Management. Rather than using a few static TVs to hold your images, MIGX will allow a user to potentially add an unlimited number, with extra fields for captions, alt tags, etc.
2. Follow Mark Hamstra's excellent tutorial on [Managing Galleries with MIGX](https://www.markhamstra.com/modx-blog/2012/04/managing-galleries-with-migx/). Set it up on either your home page or a dedicated 'Slider' resource

Once you've done that, you need to make some adjustments to use the **parseMIGXtoGallery** snippet on multiple pages:

```
$output = array();
$sliderID = $modx->getOption('sliderRes');
$sliderRes = $modx->getObject('modResource',$sliderID);
if ($sliderRes) {
    $sliderTV = $sliderRes->getTVValue('nameOfSliderTV');
    $input = $modx->fromJSON($sliderTV);
    if (!$input || empty($tpl)) return 'no stuff';
    foreach ($input as $row) {
      if (isset($set) && !empty($set) && ($set != $row['set'])) continue;
      $output[] = $modx->getChunk($tpl, $row);
    }
}
return implode("\n", $output);
```

You need to replace `nameOfSliderTV` with... the name of your slider TV.

Then instead of using the `input` option on the snippet, add `&sliderRes` and set it to the id of your slider resource (let's assume it is 6):

```
[[mh.parseMIGXToGallery? 
  &tpl=`mh.images.gallery.tpl` 
  &sliderRes=`6` 
  &set=`name of the set`
]]
```

Note that this way you can actually set up multiple slideshows on your slideshow resource using Sets.

Comment: it seems I'll have to play around with this for a bit to get the hang of it and see if it does the trick for me. Thank you, I will post feedback once I've tried it properly.